# Can I look for collision detection between two objects not attached to the script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am currently having a few issues with collision detection in my game. I have a prefab which is getting spawned in using instantiate(), this object has

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "present")
    {
        gameScore++;
        Destroy(col.gameObject);

    }
}
```

So, when the collision occurs, it destroys the object and adds 1 to the score.

I use this to set the score:

```
public void setScore()
{
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + gameScore.ToString();
}
```

and I have tested this in a different scenario and it worked just fine.

When the game plays, when the collision occurs, it deletes the object but doesn't change the visible score in game.

I believe this is due to the fact that I can't assign the public text variable

```
 public Text scoreText;
```

to prefab.

Because of this, I have tried to attach it to a empty object in my scene in the hope of it working. It didn't.

I have spent a few hours trying to work this out now and its slowly driving me crazy :) 
Would really appreciate any input.
Thank you!

P.S - I was thinking maybe if I could look for the collision in the script but not needing it attached to the object, possibly that would work? - I have no clue how to do that however

Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

so first of all, this is the wrong place to post this question! This is StackOverflow.com but your question should be on [StackOverflow GameDev](http://gamedev.stackoverflow.com).
Now since I can't move your question I will rather try to answer it. Or at least take a guess. Are you calling your setScore function anywhere again? Don't you think it should be:

`void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
      if(col.gameObject.tag == "present")
      {
           gameScore++;
           setScore() //HERES THE CHANGE
           Destroy(col.gameObject);
      }
}`

I know this is a basic answer but sometimes you lose sight of the wood for the trees so....

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry, I just assumed due to the amount of unity related stuff on here that this is the place to put it! 

I have tried it there as well. For some reason, the object is getting destroyed but no score is getting added on?

Comment: Okay, it's been a while since toying with Unity but I will just recap to check we are on the same page: You have a scene with 3 Objects. 2 *GameObjects* (Your Collider and your "present") and a *Label* called score. The interaction between the gameobejcts seems to work well the problem must be the way you update your lable. In order to update your label you would need to have a variable of type Label within your "Present"-GO and then in the editor assign your gameScore label to that variable so you could update the text shown. Do you have that? If not, try it and also post all your errors.